# Importing data from Excel to SQL through webpage - Searching for phrases

Tags: sql, vb.net, vba, excel

Very low-level programmer tasked with handling something I don't really understand, here.

My company has a webpage that takes a customer's Excel document, reads the data, and moves it to a SQL database. It isn't too sophisticated: it apparently looks for data in a particular cell (e.g., "The cell below the column named "OrderNumber") using Excel's Name Manager as a guide.

```
If IsDBNull(xlRS.Fields("OrderNumber").Value) OrElse IsNothing(xlRS.Fields("OrderNumber").Value) Then
    strPartNumber = ""
Else
    strPartNumber = Trim(xlRS.Fields("OrderNumber").Value)
```

However, each of the customers that will be using this page uses a slightly different Excel form. Although every one will have an "Order Number" column, its location on the form will vary from customer to customer. Most of them can't be persuaded to use our standardized template, so I need to find out if there's a better way to do this.

I'm not sure whether I'm putting this correctly, but using VB.net, is it possible to locate an Excel form cell by searching for a phrase (e.g., "Order"), instead of providing an exact location? If not, what could be used to get around that limitation?

Comment: Too little code to really get any idea of what's really going on. What is `xlRS` here?

Comment: @TimWilliams i think it is a recordset

Comment: two ways really: 1) find the relevant column (look at Range.Find method) or 2) load the cells used in the sheet into an array (not sure in VB.NET but C# would be e.g. `object[,] sheetData = (object[,])myRange.Value;`) then just have a look through the array for the relevant headers etc.

Comment: Yeah, that looks pretty crucial alright.

xlRS = New ADODB.Recordset()

Comment: @Cor_Blimey Method 1 seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'll be sure to investigate both methods further. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How is the recordset being populated?

Comment: try something like `myWorksheet.Rows(1).Find(What:="Order Number",LookIn:=XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas,LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole,MatchCase:=False)` (obviously with proper Marshal / referencing ;p)

Comment: forgot to say: This will give you the cell of the header. You then need the next cell down right? You can use the Offset method (or it might be indexed property through COM, I can't remember) of `.Offset(1,0)` / `.Offset[1,0]` to get to that cell. You need to check for a null ref after the Find in case there is no header.

Answer (score 0):

You could you ADO.NET with the appropriate data provider if the data is in a tabular format.  I do this sort of thing all the time and it works really well but only if the data is a simple table.